# Progressbar with two buttons for increase or decrease using native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, native

I am new to JS and have a task to make a progress bar with two buttons for increasing and decreasing by 10. I wrote some JS code, but its not working. Here is my HTML code:

```
<button onclick="increaseLength()">-</button>
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
<button onclick="decreaseLength()">+</button>
```

and JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        var currentLength = document.getElementById("progress.value");
        function increaseLength(){

            if (currentLength < 90) {
                currentLength += 10;
                document.getElementById(progress.value) == currentLength;
            };

            else if (currentLength > 90 && currentLength < 100) {
                currentLength == 100;
                document.getElementById(progress.value) == currentLength;

            };

            else{
                alert("You reached the maximum length of the progressbar!")
            }
        }

        function decreaseLength(çurrentLength){
            if (currentLength > 10) {
                currentLength -= 10;
                document.getElementById(progress.value).value ==            currentLength;
            };

            else if (currentLength > 0 && currentLength < 10) {
                currentLength == 0;
                document.getElementById(progress.value).value == currentLength;
            };

            else{
                alert("You reached the minimum length of the progressbar!")
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Definitely I`m missing something...

Comment: There are a lot of errors within this code.  I'm working on it right now.  Do you mean for the `-` button to call `increaseLength()` and the `+` button to call `decreaseLength()` or should it be the other way around?

Comment: "it's not working" ... wont enable anybody to help

Comment: - to decrease and + to increase

Comment: @StoykoMandzhukov okay, that's what I thought.  See my answer below for working code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code below.

HTML

```
<button onclick="decreaseLength()">-</button>
<progress id="progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
<button onclick="increaseLength()">+</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var currentLength = document.getElementById("progress").value;
        function increaseLength(){

            if (currentLength < 90) {
                currentLength += 10;
                document.getElementById('progress').value=currentLength;
            }
            else if (currentLength > 90 && currentLength < 100) {
                currentLength == 100;
                document.getElementById('progress').value=currentLength;

            }
            else{
                alert("You reached the maximum length of the progressbar!")
            }
        }

       function decreaseLength(){
            if (currentLength > 10) {
                currentLength -= 10;
                document.getElementById('progress').value=currentLength;
            }

            else if (currentLength > 0 && currentLength < 10) {
                currentLength = 0;
                document.getElementById('progress').value=currentLength;
            }

            else{
                alert("You reached the minimum length of the progressbar!")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code. Please check.

```js
var currentLength = document.getElementById("myProgress").value;

function increaseLength() {

  if (currentLength < 90) {
    currentLength += 10;
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = currentLength;
  } else if ((currentLength > 90 && currentLength < 100)) {
    currentLength == 100;
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = currentLength;
  } else {
    //alert("You reached the maximum length of the progressbar!")
  }
}

function decreaseLength(çurrentLength) {
  if (currentLength > 10) {
    currentLength -= 10;
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = currentLength;
  } else if (currentLength > 0 && currentLength < 10) {
    currentLength == 0;
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value == currentLength;
  } else {
    //alert("You reached the minimum length of the progressbar!")
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="decreaseLength()">-</button>

<progress id="myProgress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
<button onclick="increaseLength()">+</button>
```

Comment: Hi, when you call `increaseLength()` it decreases the length, and vice versa.  You may want to correct that for readability.

Comment: @freginold my mistake...will rectify it asap

Answer (score 0):

There were several errors that needed to be fixed.  Here are the major ones:

- You referenced the `<progress>` element by ID, so an ID needed to be added to it.
- Both functions needed to pull the current value of the progress bar before operating on it.
- `(progress.value)` needed to be changed to `("progress").value`
- You used `==` to assign a value; it should be `=`
- You had a parameter in the `decreaseLength()` function but no argument passed in.
- The `;`'s after the `if` and `if else` statements needed to be removed; they were stopping code execution after that point.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
<button onclick="decreaseLength();">-</button>
<progress id="progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
<button onclick="increaseLength();">+</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
        var currentLength;
        function increaseLength(){
            currentLength = document.getElementById("progress").value;
            if (currentLength < 90) {
                currentLength += 10;
                document.getElementById("progress").value = currentLength;
            }

            else if (currentLength >= 90 && currentLength < 100) {
                currentLength = 100;
                document.getElementById("progress").value = currentLength;

            }

            else{
                alert("You reached the maximum length of the progressbar!");
            }
        }

        function decreaseLength(){
            currentLength = document.getElementById("progress").value;
            if (currentLength > 10) {
                currentLength -= 10;
                document.getElementById("progress").value = currentLength;
            }

            else if (currentLength > 0 && currentLength <= 10) {
                currentLength = 0;
                document.getElementById("progress").value = currentLength;
            }

            else{
                alert("You reached the minimum length of the progressbar!");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and also for the detailed explanations.

Comment: @StoykoMandzhukov Glad to help.  If you've found that the answer works, please mark it as correct, to help other people who may come across this question in the future.